# Generating Functions and finding a closed formula

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I am being asked to find a closed formula for $a_n$ if $a_0=2$ and $a_n=a_{n-1}+n^2+1$. I don't know how to begin to answer this problem. I think that the $n^2$ is throwing me for a loop. If anyone could help me get started on answering this question, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: $a_{n}=a_0+\displaystyle \sum_{m=1}^n m^2 +  \sum_{m=1}^n 1$

Comment: I am not sure why you might want to know, but the [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) seems to be $\dfrac{2-4x+5x^2-x^3}{(1-x)^4}$

Comment: Thank you! I will use this information to help me start the problem and I'll check it with your answer.